# Generating an img-url in a rails app deployed on heroku

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, image, heroku

I make an AJAX call to the server that retrieves a `@player` and returns it to the AJAX call as `data.player`. For every Player object, there is a corresponding image saved in the assets/images folder saved in the format `"#{first_name}_#{last_name}"`.

My AJAX call (which is in `home.js.coffee`) inserts an image tag into my html like this:

```
< img src="/assets/' + data.player1.first_name + '_' + data.player1.last_name + '.jpg" alt="' + data.player1.first_name + '_' + data.player1.last_name + '" class= "playerpic" >' +`
```

While this works in my development environment, when deployed on Heroku, the image does not render, and upon inspection, the image tag in Heroku is this:

```
<img alt="Adrian_Peterson" class="playerpic" src="/assets/Adrian_Peterson-984288afb9b867130c88802cd5a1d80a.jpg">
```

- Why is this alpha-numerical code being added to my image's name?
- Is there a way to prevent this from happening?
- If not, how can I insert the image tag into my HTML from `home.js.coffee` and account for the alpha-numerical code that Heroku is adding onto my image names?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The alpha-numeric added to the end of your image tag is added by rails when you compile your assets, see [the Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark) for more information on the subject, but basically it helps with caching your assets on people's browsers.
- 

> Fingerprinting is enabled by default for production and disabled for all other environments. You can enable or disable it in your configuration through the config.assets.digest option.
>
> The cleanest way for you to get the image onto your page will probably be returning the image path in your JSON response rather than trying to construct it every time.

Comment: Cool, thanks. What can I use to get the image path in the controller so that I can return it in my JSON response?

Comment: The easiest way to do what you're looking for would probably be to use something like [rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl), a JSON templating system, rather than having all of this in your controller. That said, you could pass it using a string like `"#{player1.first_name}_#{player1.last_name}"` then interpreting that in your JS to create the image tag.

Comment: Thanks. I am passing a string like that now, but I am having trouble figuring out how to turn it into an image_tag that takes the alpha-numeric code into account using javascript or ERB imbedded in the JS. Do you know how to accomplish this? Thanks again

Comment: You shouldn't need to take that into account, it'll find them either way. Are the images all in your `app/assets/images` directory? If you're trying to upload them dynamically your problem is that Heroku doesn't allow for local storage, and you'll have to look into storing them on something like S3.

Comment: Yes, my images are in app/assets/images, and when I first load the page, the images load without a problem (using an ERB image_tag in home.html.erb). The issue only arises when I insert the new @player's image using AJAX.

Comment: I tried disabling fingerprinting through config.asset.digest, but when I did this, none of my JS or CSS loaded when deployed to Heroku. Do you know of a way to turn off fingerprinting for the assets but still have my JS/CSS load correctly? Thanks again

Comment: It's been a while since I used Heroku, but from what I can remember try precompiling your assets locally and see if that'll work? Heroku might be overwriting your prefs when it compiles them, but your app is looking for them without. Again, just a best guess.

Comment: I always precompile my assets locally before pushing to heroku, so I don't think this is the issue.

Comment: If this is still an issue, try running your server in production locally to diagnose the issue (rails s -e production). It's hard for me to guess at from here.